# maven-enforcer-plugin issue while creating org.jenkins-ci.plugins in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I try to get a minimal empty jenkins plugin to compile and show in a jetty jenkins.

I created a new Java Project and made it into a maven project.
`Right Click -> Configure -> Into Maven`.

My problem stems from the Parent.

```
Group Id: org.jenkins-ci.plugins 
Artifact Id: plugin
Version: 3.9
```

When I execute the Goal `RunAs -> Maven -> Install` I get an error.
The error string contains:

```
maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce failed: Unknown JDK version given. Should be something like "1.7"
```

I Installed multiple Java Versions in the machine so I should have some to choose from. I tried to set a deifferent JRE dependency in the Project Propererties with no effect.

A bit further up there is a relevant output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:display-info (display-info) @ ManualTestingMapper ---
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.3.9
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.8.0_162 normalized as: 1.8.0-162
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: windows Name: windows 7 Version: 6.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (display-info) @ ManualTestingMapper ---
```

My Windows environment has `JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8u152` and the PATH also points in that general direction.

How does one fix this in eclipse?
I would need to change the JDK version on a per project level.
I can not find anything useful using google - those were all dead ends fir me.

EDIT: 
I should mention that changing the Project Facets to Java 1.7 gives the enforcer output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:display-info (display-info) @ ManualTestingMapper ---
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.3.9
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.7.0_80 normalized as: 1.7.0-80
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: windows Name: windows 7 Version: 6.1
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (display-info) @ ManualTestingMapper ---
```

The error about needing JDK 1.7 is still the same though.

EDIT:
Here is my POM, I updated the IDs to something neutral.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SOGrouID</groupId>
  <artifactId>SOArtifactID</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SOName</name>
  <description>SOName is a Stackoverflow Example.</description>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

The parent POM contains

```
<requireJavaVersion>
<version>[1.8.0,)</version>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

which raises more questions than it answers.
The whole parent POM can be inspected [on github.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-pom/blob/plugin-3.9/pom.xml)

EDIT: Running the maven goal Install -X gives the exception type:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown JDK version given. Should be something like "1.7"
```

I guess "1.7" could be meant as a format example. If that is so then the plugin may be presented with an incomprehensible format string of sorts?

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml?

Comment: @Kai I added it to the question. My POM is very flat and the Parent POM is on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Kai who pointed me towards the parent POM.
There are a bunch of properties that are marked with `you-must-override`.
One of them is

```
<java.level>you-must-override-the-java.level-property</java.level>
```

The `IllegalArgumentException` comes from the string that was given.

Overriding that property in the pom removes the issue.

```
  <properties>
    <java.level>8</java.level>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't related to your installed Java version. Open the `pom.xml` and look for the maven-enforcer-plugin. I guess the configuration is wrong here, there should be something like:

```
<requireJavaVersion>
  <version>1.7</version>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

Comment: I can see how this would be a problem. I dont know where to look for it. '1.7' is nowhere to be found.